# How to test the client of a web application, especially for automation test for commercial product?

Tags: javascript, selenium, web, automated-tests, web-testing

My situation is i will do the development of the client-side of the web application. It means i will develop all the GUI(HTML,CSS), and all the javascript code which will communicate with the server done by others.

My only respobsibility is testing the code of my side. BTW, this web application will just be used by at most 4 people at a time. So there is no need to do pressure testing.

The application will be a commercial product, so i hope the testing tooles are also validated to be commercial avaiable.

Any suggestion or recommoned test tool or method for my situation?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/177538)

Comment: As Joseph stated, this post is going to lead to an array of responses and doesn't allow for a "correct" answer.

Comment: As others always say to me *"guide the OP"*. Try reading about [Software Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing) and see what fits best in your situation. Experience is the best teacher, so try them all out while you are at it.

Answer (score 0):

[Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) is good value. If you structure your script properly you can mock out that bits that call the server and just hand back whatever response you want. This means you can fully test your code without a server.